# Mount non-existing host directory into non-root container

Tags: docker

Lets say I have a container running with a *non-root* user and I want to bind-mount a volume directory from the host into that container. The container then will write to that directory. Say, the directory on the host is `/tmp/container/data`. If that path does **not** exist on the host, I observe that it gets created (by docker) with ownership *root*. As a consequence the container is not able to write anything into that directory (access denied) because my container is not running with user *root*.

Of course I can take care of creating the `/tmp/container/data` directory with correct permissions on the host side before starting the container, but this solution obviously does not scale - I will have to do it for each and every container where I want to use a bind volume from the host for which the directory does not exist.

So my question is, what's the best way to use bind-volumes from the host for directories that do not yet exist while still let a non-root container have write access to the volume.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You accurately described the normal behavior of docker, non-existent bind mounts from the docker engine will get initialized to an empty directory owned by root. Note that this doesn't happen with swarm mode, it will fail to schedule the container on the host instead.

Options to use to avoid this include:

- Using named volumes. These get initialized to the directory permissions in the image at that location. This is as easy as changing the full path on the host to a short name of the volume.
- Run the container as root, and make the entrypoint fix the permissions and drop to the user before launching the application. Something similar to this is done in a [jenkins-docker](https://github.com/bmitch3020/jenkins-docker) project I threw out on github recently.
- Include a script in the container with permissions setuid-root which performs the chown of the directory.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 are limited to cases, where the folder structure isn't nested -  as you can't (easily?) break out of the container to access the layers not directly mounted in.

Comment: What is an example of using the first option? Does this allow host binding or only docker-managed volume?