# Container can't write file in bind mounted directory, get Permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a container that's receiving `Permission denied` when trying to write to a bind mounted directory as `nifi:nifi`. The directory on the host was created under `root`, presumably by docker since the directory didn't exist when mounted.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2   root root   4096 Dec 13 09:31    fg-nifi
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  fg-nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.7.1
    volumes:
      - /host/path/fg-nifi:/container/path
```

I've tried apending both `rw` and `Z` to no avail:

```
- "/host/path/fg-nifi:/container/path:rw"
- "/host/path/fg-nifi:/container/path:Z"
```

---

A hard requirement is that the `fg-nifi` container needs to write a file to a directory that would easily be accessible to a user (on host machine) so they can grab the file to be used in an offline, disconnected environment.

---

I've read the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574425/547071) and I understand the options. I've read a ton of other SO questions, but still can't get this to work.

After a lot of googling I think I understand why the container is unable to write to the mounted directory, but I feel like I'm just doing this wrong and missing something. **How can I bind mount a host directory (that doesn't exist) to a container that needs to write to that directory as a different user?**

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile too? I believe that's where you'd create directories and add/modify users and permissions.

Comment: I don't have a Dockerfile, just using the base `apache/nifi:1.7.1` image. I've thought about creating a Dockerfile to create a custom image and then `chown` or `chmod` the directory in there. That would probably work, but seems like a lot of work for something that should be simple to specify. But I'm learning docker, so maybe I wrong.

Comment: What are your needs here : do the /host/path/fg-nifi needs to be specifically that path or can it be whatever/path/docker/will/create? Do you need to share the directory among containers? Or to other non-containerized apps?

Comment: @Marvin I'll update the question, but to answer your question, the directory is a specific path because the output of the container needs to be retrieved by another process or person (which may or may not be another docker container). The directory does not need to be shared between containers, unless there's a better option I'm missing.

Comment: What's the user running the container process? httpd or apache? You will need to grant rights to that user on that directory. Also, is the host machine Ubuntu? You might be clashing with apparmor

Comment: The user is only in the container but the uid:gid is 1000:1000 so I could create a custom image, create the user and chown the directory, just thought there might a way to avoid all that. I'm just learning Docker :). Hosts machines run either ubuntu or centos.